# The number of self-avoiding paths in the plane of length $k$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The number of self-avoiding paths in the plane of length $k$ is at most $4 \cdot 3^{k-1}$ according to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23583/self-avoidance-time-of-random-walk). Why?

My immediate thought: four options for the first move and always three choices after that. But that doesn't appear to be right; it's easy to write down examples where there are two choices at some step.

Comment: Note it does say "AT MOST". It's an upper bound.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I got it...thanks...somehow I had that "at least" in my mind..

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, the first step can be in any of four directions, but subsequent steps cannot reverse the previous step (and may not be able to take some other steps).

So, ignoring the bracketed text, there is an upper bound of $4 \cdot 3^{k-1}$.  Taking account of the bracketed text, the number of paths of length $k$, for small $k$ starting with $k=0$, are

[image]

as I drew many years ago for [OEIS A001411](https://oeis.org/A001411).  But for four steps the number is $100$ rather than the bound of $108$ since you cannot have a square path, and higher values are further below the bound.